# Some clients fail to obtain IP addresses after moving servers

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, dhcp

Last week we moved our servers to another room for security reasons, they have the same port configuration and it has seemed like nothing has changed.  The servers seem to be up and working fine, not reporting any errors and are all accessible and doing what they're supposed to be doing (for the most part).

Here is where the issue arises. About 20% of the computers (Windows 7) in our offices are not getting the correct network settings (IP, gateway, DNS, etc). I would do an `IPconfig /flushdns`, `IPconfig /release`, `IPconfig renew` and still, nothing would change.

All it would say is "local connection, no internet access".  So far the only thing I can find that fixes it, is an occasional reboot of the users computer, or unplugging the Ethernet cord from the back of the machine and then re-plugging it in.

That fix is also only temporary, the problem would occur again at some point during the week.  All the servers have static IP addresses and are on Server standard 2008 SP2.

Just for clarification again, the issue is happening on the *users'* machines, and not all of them.  If I set a static IP address to the machines, the computers work fine and I don't need do any unplugging or rebooting.  We do not want to set static IPs on all the machines, so that is not a "fix" for  us.

I can't determine if this is a DHCP or DNS issue.

Comment: Have you considered temporarily rolling the rack back to where it was and see how it works?  Bad jack in the new room perhaps?

Comment: We had the jacks tested, and the jacks are 100% working properly.  That was an initial thought of mine as well.  A friend of mine said I should reset the winsock on the servers, do you think that would work.

Comment: Nope, but hey, it's your sever to try. :)  If it's as you said, and you just moved it and it's still plugged into the same switch (port), then the software stack shouldn't care at all.  How did you test the jacks?  Were they just connection tested, or were [other tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_cable_certification#The_Tests) performed as well?

Comment: The organization I work for is affiliated with a University, so we use their internet and make it our own.  The University owns the port, so they came in with all their tools and gear and ran all sorts of tests.  What exact tests were performed?  I cannot tell you, they keep things a little close to the chest.  But they did assure me that nothing was wrong with the ports.  We are also using the exact same ethernet cords, you dont think the cords could be dying do you?

Comment: Yup, patch cords ends can get brittle/loose after sitting in the same spot for a long time and then moved.  Especially if the patches suck (like solid-core patch cables, or worse, solid-core patch cables with stranded-cable ends :) ).

Comment: Also, I dont have much experience with crossover cables.  We have one going from our switch to the firewall.  Does it matter which side is plugged into the firewall and which side into the switch?  The guy who was here previously, did not leave any sort of instructions for it.

Comment: Uhmm, I'm beginning to think you may be out of your element if you have to ask that. :)

Comment: Im not necessarily going to disagree here, a lot of this kind of just fell into my lap.  I dont have tons and tons of experience in this, the guy who was here previously quit and ive been handling most stuff by myself and learning trial by fire.  Havent had much experience with cross over cables.  Could that be the issue? The cross over cable ends  being switched?

Comment: Unfortunately this has gotten way beyond what a single Stack Exchange question can achieve.  You may want to post your cross-over cable questions as new ones (after reading up a bit on them).

Comment: I just wanted to let Techie and everyone else know, I figured out what the issue was.  The issue was coming from a home wireless router we had set up here.  Once that was unplugged it stopped pulling subnets from that router.  Silly thing!

Comment: Ahh, so the router had a DHCP server turned on?

Comment: Yup, DCHP for some reason was enabled on it.

Answer (score 1):

> **I cant determine if this is a DHCP or DNS issue.**

It looks like a DHCP issue.

I'd use ping to check packet loss from the troublesome desktop computers to the DHCP server. I'd check/swap cabling of the DHCP server.

Comment: So possible bad network cable going into the DHCP server?

Answer (score 0):

While you run `ipconfig /renew` on the client, Use [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor DHCP traffic and verify that you're actually seeing a response from the server.